# Your vote is locked in unless answer is edited

Tags: discussion, votes

If I click on voting up/down button (click again to undo) after voted up/down any answer then It gives error : your votes is now locked in unless answer is edited.

[image: vote-locked]

So, **I want to know in how-much time vote is locked and can't back unless answer is edited ?**

Comment: It locks in 5 minutes I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forever.  No really, Forever....................

If you were looking for the vote reversal timeout, you can find it here.  I did in under 2 minutes [Why can't I change my vote if the post has been edited during the initial 5mn grace period?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23701/why-cant-i-change-my-vote-if-the-post-has-been-edited-during-the-initial-5mn-gr/38759#38759)